# Validate a XSD file 

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I want to validate an XSD file (not XML). The approach i am using is to treat the XSD as any other XML file and use this [www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd) as the schema.

I am using the following code:

```
String schemaLang = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(schemaLang);
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource("C:\\Users\\aprasad\\Desktop\\XMLSchema.xsd"));
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();        
validator.validate(new StreamSource("shiporder.xsd"));
```

But i am getting the following error:

> Failed to read schema document 'XMLSchema.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not `<xsd:schema>`.

Not sure what the error is as the file path is correct.

Please tell me the correct approach to validate an XSD file.

Comment: Your problem isn't with validating your schema. As the error message says, your program cannot read `XMLSchema.xsd`. It's not getting as far as validating your own schema. The first three lines of your program need fixing before you worry about the next 2 lines. Your `shiporder.xsd` schema isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: @skaffman - can you tell what fix is needed in the 1st 3 lines? I got the code @ java2s.com

Comment: As far as reading the schema is concerned, the schema is downloaded from w3c and is not changed thereafter.

Comment: As [suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11693267/413020), you are better using [XSOM](http://xsom.java.net/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to have two additional files right beside `XMLSchema.xsd`. These are:

- [`XMLSchema.dtd`](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.dtd)
- [`datatypes.dtd`](http://www.w3.org/2001/datatypes.dtd)

`XMLSchema.xsd` references these two files.

*Right beside*, so if `XMLSchema.xsd` is located at `C:/XMLSchema.xsd` then you have to have `C:/XMLSchema.dtd` and `C:/datatypes.dtd`.

`SchemaFactory` instances use (see `SchemaFactory.setResourceResolver(LSResourceResolver)`) by default an internal class called `XMLCatalogResolver` which implements [`LSResourceResolver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSResourceResolver.html). The former (I assume) looks for referenced files beside the *referer*.

If you look *really* hard then the cause of your `SAXParseException` is a `FileNotFoundException` that says the the system couldn't find the `XMLSchema.dtd` file.

Other than this, your code is OK (and your schema too).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [javadoc for the StreamSource class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html#StreamSource%28java.lang.String%29), if you use the constructor method that takes a `String`, that string needs to be a valid URI.  For example, if you are trying to reference a local file, you may need to prefix the path with `file:/`.  Alternatively, you can pass a `File` object to the constructor:

```
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(new StreamSource("C:\\Users\\aprasad\\Desktop\\XMLSchema.xsd")));
```

In summary, it would be beneficial in this case to do some simple testing to rule out problems caused by your program not finding the necessary files, for example

```
File schemaFile1 = new File("C:\\Users\\aprasad\\Desktop\\XMLSchema.xsd");
File schemaFile2 = new File("shiporder.xsd");
assert schemaFile1.exists();
assert schemaFile2.exists();
```

Comment: If the file exists, using `File` or `StreamSource` with or without `file://` doesn't matter; referenced, missing files does.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what you are trying to achieve? If factory.newSchema(X) throws no exception, then X must be a valid schema(*). That seems a much more straightforward thing to do than validating against the schema for schema documents.

(*) the reverse isn't necessarily true of course: X might be valid against the schema for schema documents, but be invalid for other reasons, such as violating a UPA constraint.

Comment: Based on my answer I've made a little test. I've created a `Schema` by loading `XMLSchema.xsd` and validated it against itself. On an average machine loading took 30.76 seconds, validating took 232.3 milliseconds. Assuming OP wants to do _heavy_ schema file validation on the fly he/she is better off by loading the XML schema for XML documents into memory and validate files against it than by creating a new `Schema` for every input file.